# how to refresh the HTML structure for specific elements in selenium driver?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm rather new to selenium, but it seems like the driver caches the HTML initially, so any subsequent modifications to the HTML is not caught (unless page refresh).

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="questionnaire-form-step questionnaire-form-step-0">
<div class="questionnaire-form-step questionnaire-form-step-1 hide">
<div class="questionnaire-form-step questionnaire-form-step-2 hide">
```

And I have a button that takes me to the next div and hides the previous one. Button also modifies the class name, which is what I rely on in my xpath query.

```
   form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'questionnaire-form-step') and not(contains(@class, 'hide'))]")
```

For debugging, I outputted the innerHTML at each step, and it was always questionnaire-form-step-0's children.

Am I correct in my assumption? If not, how does one refresh what driver has cached without refreshing the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. You can't refresh element state (locator) when it was found.
You should re-find your element before each step to get fresh state.

Comment: I have the find_element call in a loop, so it should be re-finding the element? But I still run into this issue.

Comment: You should call driver.find_element_by_xpath and assign value to 'form variable' just only after (but not before) clicking on button. And then you can get innerHTML of correct element.